# How to fade or create a slider image change effect with React

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, slider, framer-motion

I'm building a website with React and Frame Motion and in the slider I can't make sure that when the image changes there is a transition or effect other than the simple detachment of the image change.

I tried to do the same thing using the `img` tag instead of the `backgroundImage` css property but still couldn't create the effect.

This is the component:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

function ImgSlider({ slides, children }) {
   const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0),
         length = slides.length,
         time = 4000;

   const handleNext = useCallback(() => {
      current + 1 >= length ?
         setCurrent(0) :
         setCurrent(current + 1);
   }, [current, length]);
   
   const handlePrev = () => {
      current === 0 ?
         setCurrent(length - 1) :
         setCurrent(current - 1);
   };

   useEffect(() => {
      const autoplay = setInterval(handleNext, time);
      return () => clearInterval(autoplay);
   }, [handleNext]);

   return (
      <motion.section
         className="slider flex space-around g-6"
         style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${slides[current]})` }}

         initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
         animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
         transition={{ duration: .5, ease: 'easeInOut' }}
         exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
      >

         {children}

         <button className="prev" onClick={handlePrev}>
            <span className="sr-only">Slide Precedente</span>
         </button>

         <button className="next" onClick={handleNext}>
            <span className="sr-only">Slide Successiva</span>
         </button>
      </motion.section>
   );
}

export default ImgSlider;
```

and his css:

```
/* Slider */
section.slider {
    min-height: 95vh;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    color: var(--bg);
}
section.slider button.prev, 
section.slider button.next {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
    top: 50%;
    width: 3rem;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    background-image: url(./imgs/arrow.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    opacity: .8;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
section.slider button.prev {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    left: 1rem;
    right: unset;
}
section.slider button.prev:hover, 
section.slider button.next:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I don't know how I could do... Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Thank you :)